# How to open a persistent SSH client to make a Web based File manager?

Tags: javascript, node.js, shell

I am currently using `shelljs` to make make connection everytime it needs to use a ssh function.

```
class Connection {
  constructor(id, path) {
    this.id = id;
    this.path = path;
  }

  exec(silent, ...args) {
    const { exec } = shellJS;
    const execCmd = exec(
      ['ssh ', ...args].join(' '),
      { silent }
    );
    // FormError(execCmd);
    return execCmd;
  }
}

class FileManager {
  constructor(connection) {
    this.connection = connection;
  }

  async ls(path = '') {
    const newPath = path ? `'${path}/'` : '';
    const listing = this.connection.exec(false, `"ls -l ${newPath}"`);
    return parseEntries(listing.stdout);
  }
}
```

**EDIT1:** After answer from brad, Mounting will may not work here, because

1. We have VERY limited access to that server(not sure if it can be mounted)
2. The code here is somewhat simplified. The real flow would be:

   ```
   Local -> SSH Server
   -> AnAppThatManagesCloudBuckets <command>
   -> Output
   ```

Comment: Use this maybe? https://github.com/mscdex/ssh2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more research found 3 packages that can be used to create persitent SSH client in the background:

As @ChrisG said.

1. [`ssh2`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ssh2) which is basically SSH module written in JS
2. [`pty.js`](https://github.com/chjj/pty.js/) a pseudo terminal emulator
3. [`node-pty`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-pty) A fork of `pty.js`

Answer (score 1):

Your code is subject to command injection, and is inherently insecure and likely unreliable for edge cases, like paths/filenames with reserved characters.

I would recommend a different approach entirely.  Use [SSHFS](https://github.com/libfuse/sshfs) to mount the remote filesystem.  Then, use the standard Node.js [fs API](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) to do your directory listings and such.

Comment: Damn! I didn't think of this. Sure +1 for me. But in this scenario it is not possible, you see the code I wrote is just a prototype. I would not suffice just to mount. The flow is kind of: `local->ssh server->anApplicationToMangeCloudBucketsLikeS3 <command>` I am editing my question a bit.